# how to get response from one servlet to another?

Tags: java, servlets

I have one `Servlet A` in which I put my result (e.g. `URL` ) in `JSONObject (org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject)`.I am trying to get url from `Servlet A` to `Servlet B` with passing some parameters (like `ID`).How to do this?

Is it possible?

Thanks.

Comment: I am now in 'servlet B', and i want to call sevlet A (By sending some parameters from B to A .Result depend on passing parameter)

Answer (score 0):

You can use request dispatcher and in request object you can set the attribute using `request.setAttribute()` in  Servlet A and in Servlet B you can access it using `request.getAttribute()`

```
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher(URL_PATTERN_OF_ANOTHERSERVLET);
dispatcher.forward(request,response);
```

Comment: I am now in 'servlet B', and i want to call sevlet A (By sending some parameters from B to A .Result depend on passing parameter)

Comment: Give the URL pattern of ServletA then to request dispatcher.

Answer (score 0):

Try using sessions.

Servlet A:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
session.setAttribute("id", yourValue);
```

Servlet B:

```
String str = (String)session.getAttribute("id");
```

Comment: I am now in 'servlet B', and i want to call sevlet A (By sending some parameters from B to A .Result depend on passing parameter)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the url by the following code:

```
request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.forward.request_uri")
```

And then you can navigate to another servlet using

```
response.sendRedirect("/ServletB")
```

**EDIT**

In Servlet B:

```
request.setAttribute("attributeName",StringParameter);
RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/ServletA");
rd.forward(request,response);
```

In Servlet A:

```
String r = (String)request.getAttribute("attributeName");
```

Comment: I am now in 'servlet B', and i want to call sevlet A (By sending some parameters from B to A .Result depend on passing parameter)

Comment: @Ace...see the EDIT section in my answer.